# Cause Make to build a particular target first among many independent "sibling" targets

Tags: build, makefile

Consider a mostly flat dependency tree where 1 target directly depends on 100 leaves. Each of the leaves is independent from one another. You have an 8-core machine to chug through the queue of leaves, and will be invoking Make with the `-j` option.

99 of those leaves take 10 seconds apiece to execute. However, 1 of those leaves (call it target `X`) is special in that it takes 2 minutes to execute. Since all 100 leaves are at an equivalent "position" in the topological ordering, presumably the order in which they will be executed is nondeterministic.  However, it will make a significant difference to the overall build time if `X` ends up being the last leaf processed in the queue (~4 minutes overall), vs. being the first leaf in the queue (~2 minutes overall).

We wish to "hide" the entirety of `X`'s build time within the execution of the other leaf nodes.

Is there a way to force `X` to be the "first among equals" in Make's queue?

Comment: One normally does this by listing `X` as a dependency of the other *leaf nodes*.  Dependencies are built first.

Comment: The problem with listing `X` as a prerequisite of all the other nodes is that then none of those nodes will start until `X` completes.  My impression is that kostmo wants them to run in parallel, but that `X` should be started first.

Answer (score 1):

Even in parallel build mode, make still walks the prerequisites list in the same order as when building serially.  It just may invoke multiple jobs at the same time.

So, putting your "slow" target as first in the prerequisite list will cause it to be started first, even with `-j`.